# How can I pull the most recent file dropped into a folder and loop through each line in the file?

Tags: c#, loops, file, monitoring, streamreader

I have been working on my code for the past two days and keep getting an error. May, I please have help?

**Code Background**

I created a QR code generator, which successfully, monitors a folder to see when a new file is dropped into the folder (FileSystemWatcher).

When a new file is dropped, an event handler is triggered, which will pull the most recent file in the folder and read each of its lines one by one. For each line in the file, a separate QR code will be generated and saved in another folder.

**ISSUE UPDATE:**

My code successfully reads each line in the most recently dropped file in folder, and generates and saves a QR code for each line. YET, it loops through the file multiple times saving each text line more than once. I only want my service to read the line once, and then stop reading.

**My event handler triggered when a new file is added to the folder:**

***UPDATED CODE THAT Correctly read each line and WORKS (yet reads each line more than once, still need help)!!!!!***

```
        private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)                         // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
        {
            LogData log = new LogData();
            Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);


            DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Desktop\BarCodeData\");

            FileInfo[] files = directoryInfo.GetFiles();                                            // list of files in the directory (output folder)DateTime recentWrite = DateTime.MinValue; // early datetime to compare to
            DateTime recentWrite = DateTime.MinValue;                                               // early datetime to compare toFileInfo recentFile = null;

            string latestFile = null;


            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                
                if (file.Extension == ".txt")
                {
                    if (file.LastWriteTime > recentWrite)
                    {
                        recentWrite = file.LastWriteTime;
                        recentFile = file;

                        latestFile = recentFile.FullName;

                        var TotalLines = LineCount.GetMaxRowCount(latestFile);

                        string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(latestFile);

                        foreach (string line in readText)           //doing this for every file if in first foreach loop, need outside forloop so only does the 
                        {
                            int counter = 0;
                            while (counter < TotalLines)
                            {
                                string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.f").Replace('/', '_').Replace(':', '_');
                                var name = date + "_line" + counter.ToString()+".png";

                                Bitmap bmap = QR.Encoder(line);

                                QR.SaveImage(bmap, line, name, @"C:\Users\Desktop\BarCodeImages\");

                                log.Write(DateTime.Now + " Maintanence Data Log, " + e.Name + ", has been encoded and QR image has been saved to the BarCodeImages folder." + counter.ToString());

                                counter++;
                            }
                        } 
     
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Yet, each line is being saved as an image multiple time. How do I only have my foreach (string line in readText) stop looping after it reads each line?

Do I use the lock method??? If so, were?
In the save image method, or in the foreach loop?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure to close the `StreamReader` after reading from the file so that other processes can access it. You can do this by wrapping it in a `using` statement, which will automatically dispose of the object when you're done with it.

Also there is a note about that in the documentation for [`StreamReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=net-7.0#remarks) class:

> This type implements the [`IDisposable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable) interface. When you have finished using the type, you should dispose of it either directly or indirectly. To dispose of the type directly, call its `Dispose` method in a `try`/`catch` block. To dispose of it indirectly, use a language construct such as `using` (in C#) or `Using` (in Visual Basic). For more information, see the "Using an Object that Implements IDisposable" section in the IDisposable interface topic.

```
private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);

    var file = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Desktop\BarCodeData\").GetFiles().OrderByDescending(o => o.CreationTime).FirstOrDefault();
    var filePath = file.DirectoryName + "\\" + file.Name;

    using(var readerObject = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        string fileLine;
        while ((fileLine = readerObject.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            using (var bmap = QR.Encoder(fileLine))
            {
                QR.SaveImage(bmap, fileLine, @"C:\Users\Desktop\BarCodeImages\");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You should use [`using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) statement on the `StreamReader` object to release any unmanaged file handle. If you don't dispose of the object properly, these file handle may remain in use even after your code has finished executing which could cause issues like yours in scenarios when you need to access the same resource again.

It is also possible that the file has changed before the file processing was finished and the `OnChanged` method was finished working. in this case it will still be open and will not be able to reopen. but we don't need this double processing.

In a completely correct program it is worthwhile making sure that QR codes are not generated twice for one line, but this solution depends on your architecture and is outside the context of the current question. In a simple scenario you can use the [`lock` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock) to quickly fix the problem:

```
// Remember that this code is only for the purpose of demonstrating the locking mechanism
private static object lockObject = new object();
private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);

    var file = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Desktop\BarCodeData\").GetFiles().OrderByDescending(o => o.CreationTime).FirstOrDefault();
    var filePath = file.DirectoryName + "\\" + file.Name;

    lock(lockObject)
    {
        using(var readerObject = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            string fileLine;
            while ((fileLine = readerObject.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                using (var bmap = QR.Encoder(fileLine))
                {
                    QR.SaveImage(bmap, fileLine, @"C:\Users\Desktop\BarCodeImages\");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me! I did not work :(. I still got the "another process is using the file, so can't access it", but this time at the "using (var ReaderObject = new StreamReader(FileName))" line.

Comment: Also, my using format is different, for it states it is not available in C# 7.3 so that is why my format is different. Could this be the cause?

Comment: Yeee.  The C# feature that allows using statements without braces was introduced in C# 8.0. This feature is called "using declarations". In older versions you can use it in old style with braces.  I fixed my answer.

Comment: I still won't work. It get's to the using statement then gives me the error.

It works when I first start the service, and drop a single line file. Yet, with the service running, when I drop another single line file, I get the error at the using statement. 

ALSO, it wont work for files with multiple lines. When I start the service, and drop in a multi-line file, it stops right away at the using statement.

Also, thank you for helping me.

Comment: I am trying to look up way to combine the streamreader and directoryinfo variables in one foreach loop.

If the file variable and readerObject are in the same loop, I think it should work??

Comment: @GStack11 now I'm really not sure. I think that it can depend on QR library implementation. And it's strange that your service stops  right away at the using statement.

Comment: The reason might be that the trigger is triggered before the handler has finished working with the previous file change. in this case you should do several things globally. 1. add blocking processing by means of competitive access mechanisms. 2. do not re-generate QR for already existing lines to speed up processing and reduce number of operations.

Comment: Hi!!! My code now works without errors (see updated post above), but I am getting the error you predicted with the lines being read more than once. 

I want to use your lock method idea, but where would I add it in my code? In the save image method or QR generator code which encodes and saves each QR encoded file line?

Thank you.

Comment: @GStack11 I'm glad to hear that you solved the previous problem. I'm afraid that the one-time processing solution is more complicated because you need to delete previously processed lines from the file or save a separate list of previously processed lines to check when processing a line if it has already been processed before.

Comment: Does it have to do with the placement of my counter which keeps track of the line number?

Could I do an if statment? If filename != Name1 then go through the loop?

Comment: @GStack11 as I can understand you do not need to process all lines in the file, but only those that have not been processed before? this means that you need to store the correspondence of files and already processed lines in them (if lines are added from the bottom, otherwise it gets a bit more complicated). Consequently, you need to use a counter not from 0, but from the value of the last line processed last time + 1

Answer (score 0):

youı should open file for Shared writing/reading. Following are the sample codes for shared reading with using Stream Reader:

```
 string filePath = "";
 using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
 using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
 {
     reader.ReadLine();
 }
```

Note: You need to close StreamReader and FileStream. Using does this for you (and disposes it so it's GC'd sooner). The using statement automatically disposes classes that implements the IDisposable interface.

Comment: where would I add the filestream? In my watcher code? It does not let me use it in my eventhandler OnChange method for the file is still be accessed by the filesystemwatcher so it can not open the file to read each line.